# Prevent two particular nodes from overlapping in arbor.js

Tags: visualization, arbor.js

I have drawn a graph using arborjs with about 15-20 nodes. Is there a way to ensure that two particular nodes never overlap. In fact, it would be better if they have a quite large distance between them or are simply situated at the extremes of the canvas.

Comment: Have you tried giving a higher value for repulsion (e.g. 10000)?

Comment: Yes. Though the hack that finally worked for me was setting up an edge between them with a custom length.

Comment: That may work with 15-20 nodes. Although using it on complex graphs with far more nodes will cause a lot of overhead.